# User exists in aspnet_membership table but getUser still returns null

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-membership

In my database I have the table aspnet_membership. In the application I am implementing the forgot password functionality. When the user is using this functionality he obviously isn't logged in. So the user enters his e-mail address of which he can't remember the password and in my code I try to get the correct MembershipUser object by executing this line of code:

```
var user = Membership.GetUser(username);
```

While testing, I enter and existing e-mail address but the function GetUser still returns null. I am sure the e-mail address exists by checking the content of the table. I cannot figure out what the reason is why I still get the null value returned. Can anyone tell me why GetUser returns null in this scenario?

Comment: you're referencing email address several times but the GetUser function expects a username, are the two one in the same on your system?

Comment: yes, username = e-mail address in this application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the username isn't actually stored in the aspnet_membership table (assuming default implementation) - username is in `aspnet_users`.

I would try doing the following and seeing if you get a result:

```
declare @email nvarchar(50)
set @email = N'whateveremailyouarehavingproblemswith'

select * 
from aspnet_membership m 
inner join aspnet_users u on m.userId = u.userId 
where m.email = @email 
    and u.username = @email
```

if nothing is returned from this query, then either your usernames and emails aren't matching, or that user does indeed not exist.

Comment: thank you, I didn't think of the aspnet_users. There the username wasn't known so in that case it isn't strange the method returned null.

Comment: I'm having this same problem, but in my case both the membership and the user exist, and it's still returning null. Other usernames work fine, just this one.

Comment: Are you sure there isn't a space at the end of their username or something?  There's no reason for this not to work

Comment: @DCShannon I am also facing the same issue, my user exists both in membership and users and even with above query is its retuning the user, but its not working with GetUser method. Did u find any solution on it.

Comment: @Kiran Not that I recall, sorry